# C# .svg file to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, .net, svg, png

I need to convert the selected .svg file to System.Drawing.Image object, so I can resize it and save it as .png. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Svg.SvgDocument svgDocument = SVGParser.GetSvgDocument(mPath);
image = svgDocument.Draw();
```

But it gives me out of memory error.

Comment: How should i use SVGParser ? is there any nuget ??

Answer (score -4, accepted):

So,

```
SVGParser.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(4000, 4000);
svgDocument = SVGParser.GetSvgDocument(mPath);
var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
image = bitmap;
```

Comment: How should i use SVGParser ? is there any nuget ??

Comment: You should place a link to the library you are using on the example because without it the answer is quite useless

Comment: He used a package called svg. To install it simply run the following in the package manager: Install-Package Svg

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [SVG Rendering Engine Lib](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG):

```
Install-Package Svg
```

It's quite easy to draw images using it:

```
var svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(imagePath);

using(var Image = new Bitmap(svgDoc.Draw()))
{
    Image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));
}
```

In this example i'm using a handler to display the image on the browser but you can easily save it on some folder just by changing the first parameter of the Save method.

Comment: How do you get this to work in a loop and not trash the 2nd and subsequent images? Do you know?

Comment: @toddmo what do you mean by trash the 2nd ? You could try to put the `svgDoc` into an `using` like the `Image`

Comment: what is context in your example? it's not declared

Comment: @CodingYourLife the context is the `HttpContext`, i'm using this inside a handler, so the context is given as a parameter on the `ProcessRequest` method

Answer (score 0):

The resource Miljan Vulovic used is svg (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=svg).

Link is only valid until July 2021, it might be available on GitHub by then, but I'm not sure.

Anyways his solution works for me.